# code snipped where a form call itself when submiting

Tags: forms

I am creating a custom module that I would like to use to display a form, from a module. The form queries a database and displays some information. The database connection is working, and the data has been retrieved successfully. The form has also been displayed successfully, but what I can figure out is how to link all together to have the page displayed again when submitting the form. My code is:

```
<?php

function menu($may_cache) {
    $items = array();
    $items['admin/reporting/report_details'] = array(
        'title' => 'Report: User details by stores',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'page callback' => 'say_report_details',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );  
return $items;
}

// This function should execute the logic if the $_GET variable is set
function say_report_details($values = array()) {
    // The $_GET logic will be somtehing like this
    // if (count($_GET) > 0) 
    // Get all the form values from the $_GET wit something like:
    // if (count($_GET) > 0) {
    // $start = mktime(0, 0, 0, $_GET['from_month'], $_GET['from_day'],

    $_GET['from_year']);
    //   $end = mktime(23, 59, 59, $_GET['to_month'], $_GET['to_day'], $_GET['to_year']);
    if ($_GET['store'] > 0) {
        $form = drupal_get_form("report_details_form");
        $output = theme("report_page", $form, $output);
        return $output;
    }


function report_details_form() {
    $form["search"] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Search params'),
        '#collapsible' => FALSE,
        '#tree' => TRUE,
    );
    for ($i = 1; $i < 32; $i++) {
        $days_opt[$i] = $i;
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
        $month_opt[$i] = $i;
    }
    for ($i = 2008; $i < date("Y") + 3; $i++) {
        $year_opt[$i] = $i;
    }
    $form["search"]["from_day"] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'Date from',
        '#options' => $days_opt,
        '#default_value' => (($_GET['from_day'] == "") ? date("d") : $_GET['from_day'])
    );
    $form["search"]["from_month"] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => '&nbsp;',
        '#options' => $month_opt,
        '#default_value' => (($_GET['from_month'] == "") ? date("m") : $_GET['from_month'])
    );
    $form["search"]["from_year"] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => '&nbsp;',
        '#options' => $year_opt,
        '#default_value' => (($_GET['from_year'] == "") ? date("Y") : $_GET['from_year'])
    );
    $form["search"]["to_day"] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'Date to',
        '#options' => $days_opt,
        '#default_value' => (($_GET['to_day'] == "") ? date("d") : $_GET['to_day'])
    );
    $form["search"]["to_month"] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => '&nbsp;',
        '#options' => $month_opt,
        '#default_value' => (($_GET['to_month'] == "") ? date("m") : $_GET['to_month'])
    );
    $form["search"]["to_year"] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => '&nbsp;',
        '#options' => $year_opt,
        '#default_value' => (($_GET['to_year'] == "") ? date("Y") : $_GET['to_year'])
    );
    $result = db_query('SELECT taxonomy_term_data.name, taxonomy_term_data.tid FROM 
    taxonomy_term_data WHERE vid = 10');
    $strs = array("all" => "All");
    foreach ($result as $store) {
        $strs[$store->tid] = $store->name;
    }
    $form["search"]["store"] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'Stores',
        '#options' => $strs,
        '#default_value' => $_GET['store']
    );
    $form["submit"] = array("#type" => "submit", "#value" => "Show report");
    return $form;
}
function theme_report_page($form, $result = array()) {
    $output = '
    <div id="report_form">
    '. $form .'
    </div> 
    <div id="report_result">
    '. $result .'
    </div>
    ';
    return $output;
}

function theme_report_details_form($form) {
    unset($form['search']['from_day']['#title']);
    unset($form['search']['from_month']['#title']);
    unset($form['search']['from_year']['#title']);
    unset($form['search']['to_day']['#title']);
    unset($form['search']['to_month']['#title']);
    unset($form['search']['to_year']['#title']);
    unset($form['search']['store']['#title']);
    $output = "<fieldset>
    <legend>Search params</legend>
    <div class='fieldtitles'>". t('Date From') .":</div>
    ". drupal_render($form['search']['from_day']) ."
    ". drupal_render($form['search']['from_month']) ."
    ". drupal_render($form['search']['from_year']) ."
    <div class='clearing'>&nbsp;</div>
    <div class='fieldtitles'>". t('Date To') .":</div>
    ". drupal_render($form['search']['to_day']) ."
    ". drupal_render($form['search']['to_month']) ."
    ". drupal_render($form['search']['to_year']) ."
    <div class='clearing'>&nbsp;</div>
    <div class='fieldtitles'>". t('Store') .":</div>
    ". drupal_render($form['search']['store']) ."
    <div class='clearing'>&nbsp;</div>
    ". drupal_render($form['submit']) ."
    </fieldset>";
    unset($form['search']);
    $output .= drupal_render($form);
    return $output;
}

function report_details_form_submit($form_id, $form_values) {
    $query = "";
    // This next line is the one we are having an issue right now, as is trowing an 
    error due to $form_values is empty for some UNKNOWN reason...
    foreach ($form_values['search'] as $key => $value) {
        $query .= "&". $key ."=". $value;
    }
    return array('admin/reporting/report_details', $query);
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you want to do......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `function report_details_form()` to `function report_details_form(&$form_state)`

You will also need to change `function report_details_form_submit($form_id, $form_values)` to `function report_details_form_submit($form_id, $form_state)`

I would highly recommend reading through the [Form API Quickstart Guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826) for this type of form.

Also, if you are not already using it, install the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module so you can access the [dpm](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm)() function.

From here you can add `dpm($form_values);` to visually debug form variables.